# Managing multiple GA4 tracking accounts

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, micro-frontend, google-analytics-4

Our application is based on micro-frontend architecture using Reactjs and we are using a separate GA4 tracking account for each of the micro frontend apps. We are facing some issues with the events from one account being sent to another.

For example, consider two applications A and B. They have two different tracking ids `G-ABC` and `G-XYZ` respectively. Now, when I access the app A, `G-ABC` is intialized and then now when I open the app B, `G-XYZ` ​gets initialized. And events from B is sent to ​`G-ABC​`
I assume this could be something to do with the cookies `_ga_XXX`. I see multiple of those cookies. Is there a way to cleanup one account before accessing the other one?

This is how we initialize the GA4 Tracking on each of the apps using `react-ga4` library.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.initialize(TRACKING_ID, {
      gaOptions: {
        cookieExpires: 604800,
        userId: userId,
        siteSpeedSampleRate: 100,
        cookieUpdate: true,
      },
    });
  }, []);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you using siteSpeedSampleRate ?

Comment: Ummm, I guess maybe it's not needed anymore as GA4 has removed that property. But it was originally added in UA to track 100% of all page loads. @titleLogin